# React-Native Checkbox can't be unchecked

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a CheckBox in my react-native application. When pressed, it can activate. However when pressed again, it doesn't uncheck itself. What am I doing wrong?

```js
export default class MyClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            checked: false
        };
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <CheckBox
                    title='Click Here'
                    checked={this.state.checked}
                    onChange={() => {this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})}}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried out the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the `Checkbox` you are using, you have to use correct `prop` for changing the state

- If you are using [React Native Element Checkbox](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html#props), you have to change the state like this:

```
<CheckBox
   ...
   checked={this.state.checked}
   onPress={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
 />
```

- If you are using [React Native Checkbox](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-checkbox), you have to change the state with these props

```
<CheckBox
   ...
   value={this.state.checked}
   onValueChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

right method will depend on the checkbox you are using. Please go through the props list of the checkbox you are using here.

If you are using 'react-native-checkbox' use `onValueChange` instead of `onChange`.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-checkbox

If you're using checkbox from react-native-elements use `onPress` instead of `onChange`.

https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html#props

hope this helps